# jooq- fetching a single value

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I had a question.. Why do I have repeat what I have selected in the fetch method.

```
Date minDate = getDSLContext()
    .select(CON_CAL_INSTANCE.DATE.min())
    .from(CON_CAL_INSTANCE)
    .join(CON_CAL_TEMPLATES)
    .on(CON_CAL_INSTANCE.TEMPLATE_ID.eq(CON_CAL_TEMPLATES.ID))
    .where(CON_CAL_TEMPLATES.ENTRY_TYPE.in("REPT", "HRPT"))
    .fetchOne(CON_CAL_INSTANCE.DATE.min());
```

So I have provided `CON_CAL_INSTANCE.DATE.min()` in my select clause, why do I have to repeat it in `fetchOne(CON_CAL_INSTANCE.DATE.min())`?

Or am I not doing this right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're doing it right. The way the jOOQ DSL is constructed with Java generics, your [`ResultQuery<Record1<Date>>`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html) doesn't *"know"* it is selecting only a single value, even if the `ResultQuery` uses [`Record1`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record1.html) as a row type.

Apart from repeating the column, you have some other options:

```
ResultQuery<Record1<Date>> query = // ...

// Use two method calls (this may result in a NullPointerException!
// as fetchOne() may return null):
Date date1 = query.fetchOne().value1();

// Use fetchValue():
Date date2 = getDSLContext().fetchValue(query);
```

See also the [`DSLContext.fetchValue()` Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchValue%28org.jooq.ResultQuery%29).

#### Using a more LINQ-style syntax

On a side-note, there had been discussions in the past about using a more LINQ-style syntax in the jOOQ API:

```
from Table
where Predicates
select Projection
```

What may look like a good idea at first is raising new questions:

1. What about the `ORDER BY`, `FOR UPDATE` clauses, which should still be placed after `SELECT`. ([See this post for details](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1555/10-easy-steps-to-a-complete-understanding-of-sql)).
2. What about set operations, like `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`.

[I've also written about the difference between lexical and logical order of operations in SQL, here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/)

These open issues made us stick with the standard SQL syntax.