# JOOQ - convert fetchOne().into() to fetchValue(query)

Tags: java, orm, jooq

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22344693/1490322), the author mentions that to avoid NPE the `fetchValue(query)` method can be used.  The problem is that how exactly can the OP's code be converted into a `query`?  I have similar code, pasted below, and would like to turn it into a query also.

```
        return jooqDSLContext.select()
                .from(CL_LOGIN)
                .join(CL_USERS)
                .on(CL_LOGIN.CL_USER_ID.eq(CL_USERS.CL_USER_ID))
                .where(CL_USERS.EMAIL1.eq(email))
                .fetchOne().into(CL_LOGIN);
```

JOOQ is very powerful and has many capabilities, but unfortunately everything I have tried to make a standalone query object with a join does not even compile.

EDIT:  The answer provided did help me side-step the need to have a query object.  But for those that want to know how to get a query object you can use the `getQuery()` method... see example below.

```
        SelectQuery<Record1<String>> query = jooqDSLContext.select(USER_LOGIN.ACCOUNT_STATUS)
            .from(USER_LOGIN)
            .where(USER_LOGIN.USER_ID.eq(userId))
            .getQuery();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe the signature of the method [`DSLContext.fetchValue(ResultQuery<R>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchValue-org.jooq.ResultQuery-), where `R extends Record1<T>`. This means that the expected row type of the query is `Record1<T>` with any arbitrary `<T>` type. In other words, you must project exactly one column in your `SELECT` clause.

You seem to want to project the entire record of type `CL_LOGIN`, so `fetchValue()` is not applicable to your use-case.

But note, there's also [`ResultQuery.fetchOneInto(Table)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOneInto-org.jooq.Table-), which is a convenience method wrapping that null check and the `into()` call. So, just write:

```
return jooqDSLContext.select()
        .from(CL_LOGIN)
        .join(CL_USERS)
        .on(CL_LOGIN.CL_USER_ID.eq(CL_USERS.CL_USER_ID))
        .where(CL_USERS.EMAIL1.eq(email))
        .fetchOneInto(CL_LOGIN);
```

Comment: Thank you Lukas.  I read so much of the answers you post on here and in other sites.  Your work is very much appreciated.